# HIVE Metastore DataModeling documentation?

Tags: hadoop, open-source, hive

Hive Table relays on its meta store,
Which has Tables namely TBLS, SDS INXD, ....

Is there any documentation about the data model of meta store, both diagram and description ?

Since its open source, there must be a repository, maintaining the hive meta store  data modeling , documentation for each Hive release

Answer (score 5):

This is the [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12471108/HiveMetaStore.pdf) to metastore ER diagram. You might find the original [Hive paper](http://i.stanford.edu/~ragho/hive-icde2010.pdf) useful. I would also suggest you to browse through the official Hive documentation and read the good book `Programming Hive`.